# Implementation of generic interfaces in c#

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and trying to learn generic interfaces. I am getting an error when trying to implement GetComments. Error: `'cannot convert expression type 'WallGetObject' to return type T'`. 
Is it possible to do something like that? Thanks.

```
interface IInterface
{
    T GetComments<T>(int id);
}


public class A: IInterface
{
    public T GetComments<T>()
    {
        WallGetObject item
        //... getting item
        return item
    }
}

public class B : IInterface
{
     public T GetComments<T>()
      {
        TopicFeedObject item
        //... getting item
        return item
    }
}


public class MainClass()
{

var item1 = new A();
var item2 = new B();

var list = new List<IInterface>();
list.Add(item1);
list.Add(item2);


foreach (var i in list)
{
  i.GetComments(5);
}
```

Comment: You are mixing generic interface with generic method. The way you defined it, you have non generic interface with generic method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On first glance, I believe what you are trying to do is implement an interface method that returns a different type for each concrete class. That is, `A.GetComments` should return `WallGetObject` and `B.GetComments()` should return a `TopicFeedObject`. This would be accomplished by using a generic *interface* (not a generic *method* as you have).

```
interface IInterface<T>
{
    T GetComments(int id);
}

public class A: IInterface<WallGetObject>
{
    public WallGetObject GetComments()
    {
        WallGetObject item
        //... getting item
        return item
    }
}
```

**However, this will then lead to a problem later on when you try to create a generic list of different types of `IInterface`s**. That is, creating a `List<IInterface>` requires a common base class/interface, and is simply not possible with the above.

---

**The real answer is not to use generics** here, but instead a base (abstract) class or interface on `WallGetObject` and `TopicFeedObject` that exposes the common functionality you need. For example.

```
interface IComments {}

class WallGetObject : IComments {}
class TopicFeedObject : IComments {}

interface IInterface
{
    IComments GetComments(int id);
}

public class A: IInterface
{
    public IComments GetComments()
    {
        WallGetObject item
        //... getting item
        return item
    }
}

public class B : IInterface
{
     public IComments GetComments()
     {
        TopicFeedObject item
        //... getting item
        return item
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You should declare and implement your interface like this. Note the generic type definition is moved to interface declaration instead of method declaration.

```
interface IInterface<T>
{
    T GetComments(int id);
}


public class A: IInterface<WallGetObject>
{
    public WallGetObject GetComments(int id)
    {
        WallGetObject item
        //... getting item
        return item
    }
}

public class B : IInterface<TopicFeedObject>
{
     public TopicFeedObject GetComments(int id)
     {
        TopicFeedObject item
        //... getting item
        return item
     }
}
```